# What's the coproduct of categories?

Tags: category-theory, coproduct

I'm a math student at the second year of college and I'm approaching category theory for the first time for personal interest.
An older student suggested me to start by reading "Categories for the working mathematician" by Saunders Mac Lane.
One exercise recites as follows: "Describe coproducts (and show that they really exist) in Cat, in Mon, in Grph.
My only idea is to construct the first with a disjoint union of the objects of two given categories and do the same for the arrows however I'm not sure that is allowed with classes.
Any suggestions for the other two execises would also be helpful.

ps:I'm sorry for my bad english (it's not my mother language)

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct. The coproduct of category can be constructed as you describe. You should verify it has the appropriate universal property. As Arthur notes, the issue you are worrying about is a "size issue", which can easily be solved by looking at small categories. A further note, size issues really aren't the heart of category theory and I recommend ignoring them while trying to learn the subject for the first time. I also recommend reading Emily Riehl's "Category Theory in Context" since I found it more accessible as an undergrad than the MacLane text.

Comment: Though I really like MacLane's use of universal arrows and was a bit disappointed Riehl never used them.

Comment: Another ver good book for an absolute beginner is Leinster's "Basic category theory"

Comment: Thank you all. I checked and you are right, cat is the category of small categories

Comment: Let me just emphasize that, as a second-year undergraduate, it is unlikely that you want to be reading Mac Lane. It's ideal for a second-year Ph.D. student, at least in the American system. Riehl is also rather hard, though a bit more approachable than Mac Lane. Fosco's recommendation is where I'd start.